# How to modify the CIM API hosted form

Tags: authorize.net

I wanted to modify the expiration date settings in the form hosted by Authorize.net's CIM API.
I wanted it to be displayed in 2 drop downs, one for month and the other for year, instead of a single text field (mm/yy).
Is it possible to modify the form fields in the form?
Can anyone help me in getting this done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to modify the hosted payment form as you describe.

Comment: @rhldr, please answer so this moves down the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the hosted payment form as you describe.